# Should I install the Intel Drivers for Linux to make Minecraft faster?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, ubuntu

My computer is pretty old and doesn't handle Minecraft very well. When I played on Windows 7, the max FPS I'd ever get was about 25-30. And, on top of that, the FPS would fluctuate a lot. When the 1.8 update came out in September 2014, I was disappointed because my computer wouldn't run it, and I assumed it was a graphics card problem. So I installed Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS, and found not only that I could run 1.8, but Minecraft was much faster. However I figured that the open source Ubuntu drivers would be slower than the official Intel ones for Linux. However, I'm scared to install the Intel drivers, because I don't want my Minecraft quality to go back to being as bad as it was in Windows 7, and installing the Intel drivers may prevent my computer from running 1.8 again. So, should I install the Intel drivers or leave it be?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to uninstall the Intel drivers if they don't work well? I haven't tried, just curious.

Comment: I'm not all that experienced with Ubuntu, so, I'm not really sure where find the original open source drivers and reinstall them if I do go down that route.

Comment: if you want to try the installer and then undo what it did, this might help: http://askubuntu.com/a/531559/47291

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally, I assumed that the Intel driver you wanted to install was already included in your Ubuntu 14.04 installation.

I booted up into a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit), and checked the list of installed packages for the Intel driver. I found it, along with the packages needed for OpenGL support.

[image]

Even though the generic (vesa) drivers are also installed, I assume Ubuntu is automatically using your Intel drivers. If you want to double check, I [suggest finding what video driver your system is using.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system)

> Run `lshw -c video`, and look for the line with "configuration".

If the "configuration" line has `driver:i915` as it does on the askubuntu page, then you are using the Intel drivers.